# Markdown, How do I output raw backtick escapes?

Tags: markdown

I want to output the raw backtick escapes.

I want like this :

```
`  <---  A backtick escapes
```

Comment: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `` \` `` if you are outside inlined code (in a normal paragraph): \` = `

If you want to use it in inlined code, use double backticks for inlining the section (instead of a single backtick): `` Getting a backtick ` inside inlined code ``.

If inside a code block (with four spaces at the beggining of the line), you don't have to escape it at all:

```
This is a code block and I can write `single backticks`
```